# ld.exe: cannot find src: Permission denied

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, mingw

Basically im trying to build a game engine with OpenGl and SDL. Im using a makefile to compile it but I get an error. The error started appearing after I reorganized my folder structure and I included the src folder to the include path so i can access them with the absolute path. For example `Renderer/Camera.h` instead of `../Renderer/Camera.h`.

When I try to compile my project I get this error:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find src: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:57: build] Error 1
```

This is my makefile

```
RELEASE_MACRO:=-D RELEASE
DEBUG_MACRO:=-D DEBUG
OS_MACRO:=-D
BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := -Isrc -Iinclude
LIB     := lib


#Check the OS
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
   # the compiler: gcc for C program, define as g++ for C++
   CC   := g++
   # The windows command for delete
   DEL := del
   # The windows slash for directory
   SLASH := \
   # Indicating that we dont need wine, unlike in linux
   WINE := 
   OS_MACRO +=__WINDOWS__
   SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/***/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(INCLUDE)/***/*.cpp)  $(wildcard $(SRC))

else
   # CURRENTLY NOT WORKING
   # Linux compiler for windows executables (64 bits)
   CC   := x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
   # Linux command for delete (rm -f)
   DEL := $(RM)
   # Linux slash for directory
   SLASH := '/'
   # Wine, program for executing windows apps .exe
   WINE := wine
   OS_MACRO +=__LINUX__
   SOURCES := $(shell dir . -r *.cpp)

endif


# compiler flags:
  #  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
  #  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CFLAGS:= -g -Wall


# libraries to link to the project
LIBRARIES   := -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_net -lSDL2_mixer -lmingw32 -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lglu32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image 
# the build target executable
EXECUTABLE  := game


all: build
showfiles:
    @echo $(SOURCES)
    
# Builds the executable game
build:
    echo "Building..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -L $(LIB)  $(OS_MACRO) $(DEBUG_MACRO) -o $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE) $(SOURCES) $(LIBRARIES) 

# Run the game
run:
    @echo "Executing..."
    $(WINE) $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)
# Build then run the game
build-and-run: clean build run
# Remove the executable
clean:
    @echo "Clearing..."
    $(DEL) bin$(SLASH)$(EXECUTABLE).exe
```

This is my project folder structure

[image]

Comment: What is `$(wildcard $(SRC))` supposed to do?

Comment: You showed the error message, which is good, but you didn't show the linker command that caused the error message.  That's where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/***/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(INCLUDE)/***/*.cpp)  $(wildcard $(SRC))
```

I don't know where you got that wildcard syntax from but it doesn't do what you think it does.  `***` is identical to `*` in standard glob syntax which is what GNU make uses.  Also do you really expect to find `.cpp` files in your `$(INCLUDE)` directory?  That would be very strange.

The problem, as ssbssa points to, is that `$(wildcard $(SRC))` will expand to `$(wildcard src)` which is just `src`, so you're trying to add a directory to your link line which is illegal and the linker complains.

Comment: Yeah I expect to find cpp files into my include bc i use imgui and other libraries which have cpp files and i thought it was a good idea to put it all together in the include file within a `imgui` folder.

Comment: And changing my `/***` error to `/**` didnt work, still got the same error output.

Comment: Alright, that was the mistake. Now my error output changed.

Comment: It was `$(wildcard src)`, btw

Comment: What I'm saying above is that `***` means nothing special to make.  A single `*` means "any number of characters", and so `**` means "any number of characters followed by any number of characters" which is exactly the same thing, and `***` means "any number of characters followed by any number of characters followed by any number of characters", which is also the same thing.  So you'll get the same behavior from `$(SRC)/*/*.cpp` as `$(SRC)/**/*.cpp` as `$(SRC)/***/*.cpp`.

Comment: I realized, thank you.